# How to calculate the area of a polygon given its coordinates?

Tags: carto, service-area

How to calculate the area of a polygon
given its coordinates?

{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":
[[[[40.92344999,57.76796047],
[40.92299938,57.76776019],
[40.92268825,57.76796619],
[40.92312813,57.76816647],
[40.92312813,57.76816647],
[40.92344999,57.76796047]]]]}

It uses the same method as in Area of a polygon but does the arithmetic for you.
Polygon area calculator
Area=1.551079549

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can find the area using SQL/PostGIS in CartoDB by using [ST_Area](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Area.html). You can run this in your SQL editor:

```
SELECT *, ST_Area(the_geom::geography) area FROM untitled_table_1
```

It will calculate the area for the object in each row and adds a temporary column to your table called `area` that give the area in square meters.

Comment: As more complete: `SELECT ST_Area(ST_GeomFromText('MULTIPOLYGON (((40.92344999 57.76796047,40.92299938 57.76776019,40.92268825 57.76796619, 40.92312813 57.76816647, 40.92312813 57.76816647, 40.92344999 57.76796047)))',4326)::geography);` And the result is `1028.11563305801`.

Comment: Andy Eschbacher 
Thank you for your valuable advice. Everything turned out!

And as for your fomula to calculate the number of polygons? (their coordinates are also known)
which means that number?  )))',4326)
Thank you. You are a magician :)

Answer (score 0):

The [shoelace formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula) is what you need. A full example is given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24468019/347815) in python.